# Why I can't manage anymore to access to some rule descriptions after a SonarQube upgrade?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

**Context :**

After a migration sonarQube : 3.73 -> 4.5.5

**Bug :**

When i consult some rules with the link on the top of sonar, the description does not appear but rather a javascript :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentKey' of undefined
  of undefinedCodingRulesDetailQualityProfileView.getParent @ app.js:11149
  CodingRulesDetailQualityProfileView.serializeData @ app.js:11187
  Marionette.ItemView.Marionette.View.extend.render @ app.js:3073
  Marionette.CollectionView.Marionette.View.extend.renderItemView @ app.js:3342
  Marionette.CollectionView.Marionette.View.extend.addItemView @ app.js:3293
  (anonymous function) @ app.js:3225_.each._.forEach @ sonar.js:27333
  _.each.Collection.(anonymous function) @ app.js:956
  Marionette.CollectionView.Marionette.View.extend.showCollection @ app.js:3223
    Marionette.CollectionView.Marionette.View.extend._renderChildren @ app.js:3211
  Marionette.CollectionView.Marionette.View.extend.render @ app.js:3196
  _.extend.show @ app.js:2483CodingRulesDetailView.onRender @ app.js:11589
  Marionette.triggerMethod.triggerMethod @ app.js:2134
  Marionette.ItemView.Marionette.View.extend.render @ app.js:3082
  Marionette.Layout.Marionette.ItemView.extend.render @ app.js:3647
  _.extend.show @ app.js:2483(anonymous function) @ app.js:13862
  jQuery.Callbacks.fire @ sonar.js:3200jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ sonar.js:3312
```

**Investigation**

When we see the javascript :

```
    myProfile = _.findWhere(this.options.app.qualityProfiles, {
      key: this.model.get('qProfile')
    });
    parentKey = myProfile.parentKey; // this line bug because myProfile is undefined
```

*this.options.app.qualityProfiles* -> contains all quality profiles of sonar

*key: this.model.get('qProfile')* -> get the key of a quality Profiles link to the rule

After some investigations, i found that this precise quality profile link to the rule cannot be found in database. So i supppose it's a old and deleted quality profile.

Thats can explain why the specific quality profile that’s does not exist in all quality Profiles

**Questions**

Have you ever seen this bugs ?

How sonar can resurrected theses old and deleted qualityProfiles ?

What can i do ?

Comment: If my feeling is correct, during the upgrade process you haven't copy your language plugins from the old SonarQube version to the new one.

Comment: i copy-paste plugins from the old version 3.7.3 -> 4.5.5 and its works ! Thanks :) !

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that rebuilding ES indexes will do the job.
For that delete, after backup ^^, the "data/**es**" folder of your SQ instance, then restart your server.
Indexes will be rebuilt (it may take some time depending on the size/number of your projects).